# how do i parse live html from a website and extract specific information and store it into a database with visual basic

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio, web-scraping

The info i need extracted is formatted:

```
<TD><A HREF="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxx/index.html"><IMG SRC="../xxxxx/thumbnails/xxxxx.jpg">    </A></TD>
<TD>=== <B><A HREF="http://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx/index.html">LINE 0</A></B> ===<BR>
<FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="#400080">
Line 1<BR>
Line 2<BR>
Line 3
</FONT>
</TD>
```

how do i extract the info between TD=== and /a and Line 1,2, and 3 and store it into a database from a live website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for information about scraping a website. There are a lot of tools that can help you with this, perhaps you could start here: [web scraping using visual basic (blogs.msdn.com)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/02/20/web-scraping-using-visual-basic-s-xml-support.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do using PHP, here is a PHP inbuilt function.

You can use the following function and it will give you string between ===

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("/===(.*)===/", $source, $matches);
?>
```

$source is your html and $matches will return you the array of possible strings.