# Getting Visual Basic Program to Type into an HTML <p> and <input> tag with no id/name

Tags: vb.net

So I have a program that takes a few inputs from textboxes and then adds them all up into two strings. Basically here is the problem, I am trying to get one of the strings to go into the forum post "title" and one into the forum "body". (This is not a spam program, it makes it easier for people to post ban reports for players on our server.) Here is the HTML codes for the website I am trying to type into;

---

`<p class="ipsField_content">
<input id="topic_title" class="input_text" type="text" size="60" maxlength="150" name="TopicTitle" value="" tabindex="2">
</p>`

---

The HTML code above is for the topic title area I want to type into. The problem with this is that it always says how it can not find this area.

---

'This is the HTML code for the forum body:

```
<body spellcheck="true" class="cke_show_borders">
<p>This is where I want to be able to type</p>
</body>`
```

---

With the HTML code above, I can't seem to get this VB code below to select that text area and enter in my string.

---

`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p").InnerText = post`

---

One reason is because VB doesn't allow me to use .innertext on a tag, and the other is that I do not know how to really specify which "p" tag. Like there is multiple "p" tags on this webpage, but it is the only "p" inside the "body" tag, if I could specify that somehow.

Here is the VB code I am using currently for the program.

---

`Dim Report As String
Report = YourName & Suspect2 & Server & Time2 & Reason & RulesBroken & Proof`

```
    Dim topictitle As String
    topictitle = ("" & Suspect & " - " & txtReason.Text & txtReasonCustom.Text & "")

    txtTitle.Text = topictitle
    txtPost.Text = Report`
```

`making sure that the words "sign out" is on the page to insure the webbrowser is signed in.`

```
    `Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString
        If WebBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Sign Out") Then 
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.ThisLinksToMakeNewPostOnTheWebsite.com")
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("topic_title").InnerText = txtTitle.Text
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName("body").firstchild.InnerText = txtPost.Text
        End If`
```

---

---

`this code below is used to click the submit button`

```
   `WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")`
```

---

---

`also this is the html code for the "Post New Topic" button`

```
   <input type="submit" name="dosubmit" value="Post New Topic" tabindex="50" class="input_submit" accesskey="s">
```

---

Anyways that is it. I tried to include as much information and as much lines of code as I could to show that I really am trying.
Please help, I have tried the MSDN links, but I can't seem to apply it to this.

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684478/how-do-i-parse-live-html-from-a-website-and-extract-specific-information-and-sto

Comment: i don't know what you mean by dupe, but I am trying to type into things on the HTML page, not query data from an HTML page.

Comment: well, it'd help you parse the DOM to find whatever tags you need...

Comment: @MarcB so if I was to parse the DOM, would I be able to input text into the box and the webpage still be live?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I think you are using the WebBrowser control. There is a much less resource hogging alternative. Since you are really only interested in posting to a form, you don't need the overhead of a browser. You can use the HTTPWebRequest to POST the data/text from your textboxes directly to a URL. An example can be found here:

http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-51-httpwebrequest-post-method/

It's not the best tutorial in the world but it will get you on your way. You would of course still need to know what data you need to send to the web site.